# INSERT вставляет 2 строки вместо одной

Tags: php, mysql, insert

```
setting.php 
<?php 
$servername='localhost'; 
$data='mytest'; 
$username = "root"; 
$password = ""; 

index.php 
require_once 'setting.php'; $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mytest;charset=utf8",$username,$password);
$query = "INSERT INTO users (name,age,login,password) VALUE ('name','41','login','321')"; 
$count=$connection->exec($query); 
echo $count; 
$count = null;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Надо настроить вебсервер чтобы за favicon-кой  __не ходил__ на index.php

Answer (score -1):

Заполнение происходит по той причине, что сначала вы вводите данные в самом запросе, а потом вызываете саму команду, содержащую запрос.